# How can I access a .jls file's contents (JPEG-LS compressed) or its bitstream so that I may further compress it using C#?

Tags: c#, compression, jpeg, filestream, file-access

JPEG-LS is a lossless image compression algorithm for continuous-tone images. Images compressed using JPEG-LS results to a file with an extension of ".jls".

How may I access this file using C#, or how may I access its bitstream, so that I may further compress it?

I tried using Bitmap in C#, storing it in a Bitmap, but it does not support it. 
I tried opening it through notepad, but its been encoded in some unknown format.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CharLS](http://charls.codeplex.com/), an open-source JPEG-LS library.

Comment: I'm actually trying to work CharLS now, but its very hard to use, their API documentation is confusing, and they don't have examples. I'm using the C# version, and for some reason its very hard to work. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Just call `JpegLsDecode()` with enough output space, your input data, and a NULL info parameter.  See if it returns successful, and if so, what you got back.

Comment: Can you provide me with a sample program please?